# Spring Data JPA ManyToOne query null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've started to learn Spring Boot, I've created two entities Invoice and YearDate

When I try to search by year(id), in my log query I got null (see this part of log query)

```
http://localhost:8080/appapi/invoices/search/findByYearId?year=1

from invoice invoice0_ left outer join year_date yeardate1_ on invoice0_.year_id=yeardate1_.id where yeardate1_.id is null limit?
```

I'm using Lombok also for getters and setters

Here are all my class entities, SQL tables, and JpaRepository interface :

**SQL foreign key :**

```
KEY `fk_year` (`year_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_year` FOREIGN KEY (`year_id`) REFERENCES `YearDate` (`id`)
```

**YearDate class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="YearDate")
@Data
public class YearDate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "year_value")
    private String yearValue;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "year")
    private Set<Invoice> invoices;
}
```

**Invoice class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="invoice")
@Data
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "year_id", nullable = false)
    private YearDate year;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
}


**And The Invoice Interface:**

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {

    Page<Invoice> findByYearId(@RequestParam("year") Long id, Pageable page);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Work for me.

try to extract call in rest controller and log params

```
@GetMapping(value = "/invoices")
  public Page<Invoice> getInvoices(@RequestParam("yearId") Long yearId) {
        Page<Invoice> byYearId = invoiceRepository.findByYearId(yearId, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
        return byYearId;
}


public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {

    Page<Invoice> findByYearId(Long id, Pageable page);
}


 @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "year_id", nullable = false)
   @JsonIgnoreProperties("invoices")
    private YearDate year;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "year")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("year")
    private Set<Invoice> invoices;
```

Generated SQL :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        invoice0_.id as id1_0_,
        invoice0_.description as descript2_0_,
        invoice0_.name as name3_0_,
        invoice0_.year_id as year_id4_0_ 
    from
        invoice invoice0_ 
    left outer join
        year_date yeardate1_ 
            on invoice0_.year_id=yeardate1_.id 
    where
        yeardate1_.id=? limit ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        yeardate0_.id as id1_5_0_,
        yeardate0_.year_value as year_val2_5_0_ 
    from
        year_date yeardate0_ 
    where
        yeardate0_.id=?
```

-> **ADD @JsonIgnoreProperties("invoices") and   @JsonIgnoreProperties("year") to entities to avoid infinite json recusrsion.**

Comment: When i've add this update, i make a call like this : 
http://localhost:8080/appapi/invoices?yearId=1 & i obtain 500 internal server error with unlimited log like this : 
Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@5f5daaff<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@2041799547 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>

Answer (score 0):

I've disabled Lombok and it works

Answer (score 0):

try pass him a Year object not id is better

```
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {
    Page<Invoice> findByYear(YearDate year, Pageable page);
}
```

and in your service get this year
for exemple I create a getYears method in service:

```
@Service
public class YearService{

@Autowired
private YearRepository yearRepository;
@Autowired
private InvoiceRepository invoiceRepository;

getYears(idYear:Long){
YearDate yearParam=yearRepository.findById(id).get();
Page<Invoice> invoices=invoiceRepository.findByYear(yearParam,YourPagination)
}

}
```